# Get запросы с сохранением промежуточного результата

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket, redux

Объясните пожалуйста какие практики обычно применяются для таких вещей.

Есть react-redux приложение, которое работает с api на питоне.
Смысл в том, что есть необходимость посылать get запрос с интервалом в минуту и при этом надо сохранять промежуточный результат и на основе этого менять, скажем, стили каких-то элементов.

Вопрос состоит в следующем:

1. Необходимо ли как-то интегрировать вебсокеты, чтобы периодически инфу с сервера ? Если да, то нужно ли сначала написать какие-то сокеты на бэке, чтобы я мог на них подписываться ?
2. Или будет достаточно просто по варварски написать setInterval, скажем, в useEffect чтобы оно просто посылало запросы ?

Answer (score 1):

Для запросов раз-в-минуту websocket не нужен. Он нужен только для событий генерируемых на сервере, когда интервал на клиенте не известен.

setInterval достаточно, если на сервере не важно предыдущее состояние. Если состояние важно - нужно запускать сессии на сервере. Websocket не очень удобная замена сессий.